# Turing machine accepts any word

Tags: turing-machines

> Let M be a Turing-machine with tape alphabet = {0, 1} that does not
>   move beyond the first 64 cells of its tape. Is the problem "Does M
>   accept any word?" decidable?

1. I would say it does not accept any word because we can have words longer than 64 characters.
2. I would say it does because if it accepts any word, we don't care about the length. It always goes into accepting state.

Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: What is the *bandwidth* of a Turing machine? Is it the same as *space*?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes, bandwith and space is the same.

Comment: How exactly do you measure space? How many tapes does your machine have?

Comment: The turing machine has one tape and I think this tape has a length of 64.

Comment: Double check. This doesn’t make sense, since the input could be arbitrarily long.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the **full** text of the original problem? Can you add a reference to the place where you saws the original problem? Please read carefully the definition of a Turing machine.

Comment: That was the full text of the problem. It is from an old exam. I will try to figure out how that was meant.

Comment: *"Does it accept any word?"* Do you mean "Does there exist such an TM that accepts every word?"?  *"Is that problem decidable or not?"* What problem?

Comment: I updated the question with the full text of the original problem.

Comment: What exactly is meant by points 1. and 2.? Are you having two conflicting opinions of what the solution should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P = \{ w \in \{ 0,1 \} \mid |w| \le 64 \land w \in L(M) \}$. Since $P$ contains only words over an alphabet (i.e., a *finite* set) and all words in $P$ have bounded length, $P$ is finite. Moreover, any word $w \in \{0,1\}^\ast$ with length $|w| > 64$ is in $L(M)$ if and only if there is a prefix of $w$ which is in $P$. Thus, to decide $L(M)$, we only need to check whether the input has a prefix out of finitely many possibilities (i.e., those in $P$).

Hence, $L(M)$ is not only decidable, it is decidable *in constant time*.

Note this construction does not require any knowledge of $M$ whatsoever (in particular, there is no need to simulate $M$). We only need to show the *existence* of a TM which decides $L(M)$, not actually *construct* one.